# Add/Hide Pane To a Web Page Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a test scenario where I have an html page with a button:

- On button click show a pane on right of the page
- Load another web page in that pane
- On Click of button again, hide the page

any guidance is welcomed.

Comment: show us some code ..!!

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem yourself? What were the results? What is the issue you are running into?

Comment: Read the doc ! http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: i believe u r looking for jquerymobile panel..http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/panels/

Comment: @codebreaker: thanx, although I have tried that, but I am looking for something with little or no dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, on click toggle a pane that contains an `iframe`

```
<div id="frameDiv"><iframe></iframe></div>
<button id="showFrame">Show frame!</button>

$("#showFrame").click(function() { $("#frameDiv").toggle(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Iframe to load another web page.
Place the IFrame in an div and on click of the button you can toggle its visibility.

Suppose the div id is 'SomeDiv' then on click of the button you can either

```
$('#SomeDiv').Show() or $('#SomeDive').Hide()
```